# Repeat slide from different file

Tags: beamer

I make presentation using `beamer`. I have each section in different `.tex` file.
How can I repeat slide from file X in file Y?

I tried `\againframe{label}` but it seems to not see labeled slides from different file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you use `\input` to read the files it does work exactly as if the file would be part of the file that has the `\input`. So please show us a [minimal but working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) from `\documentclass` until `\end{document}` that illustrates the problem and can be used to analyze it and test our suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write (the name is exemplary):

```
\newcommand{\slideAA}{Your slide}
```

before the first appearance and then `\slideAA` in both cases.